# bootstrap carousel slider arrow shadow error

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

[image]

anyone experience this? the shadow on the left slider arrow is flip. The left arrow shadows appear to be right arrow shadow. 
However, when you mouseover it, it goes back to the left arrow shadow.

This only happens in Firefox. Chrome & IE dont have such error.
Anyone knows how to solve this in Firefox?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel It's fine when it viewed in FF 43.0.1. Are you referring to the `text-shadow` or `background-image` which is gradient?

Comment: http://s23.postimg.org/or2aoy5jf/image.jpg thanks Ravi. This is what i see in my firefox 44.0.2. The left arrow shadow is flip.

Comment: Are you facing issue in your system only or in other systems also? try to check after disabling all the extensions that you may have for FF.

Comment: i think only my pc. Thanks